# How to find child elements of a specific node ? with TinyXpath

Tags: xml, xpath, tinyxpath

I have successfully used TinyXpath with root node as below

```
const char* xpath ="/MyRoot/A/B";
TinyXpath::xpath_processor xp_proc(mRootElement, xpath);
```

(this will find all B under all A of MyRoot)

I wonder if I can pass non-root element to the constructor something like below

```
const char* xpath = "./A/B";
TinyXpath::xpath_processor xp_proc(A_Element, xpath);
```

**(I want to find all B under specific A, when I have A_Element)**

Thank you

Comment: Asking about specific XPath engine invocation method. Retagging

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Given this constructor definition** from the TinyXPath documentation:

```
xpath_processor (const TiXmlNode *XNp_source_tree, 
                 const char *cp_xpath_expr)
```

**You could have**:

```
xpath_processor(A_Element, "A/B");
```

provided that `A_Element` is of type `TiXmlNode*`

This will select all `B` elements that are children of an `A` element that is a child of the element referenced by `A_Element`.

In case you want to select all `B` elements that are children of the element referenced by `A_Element`, then the call should be:

```
xpath_processor(A_Element, "B");
```